# Obtener formato XML de C# a PHP

Tags: php, c#

He creado un pequeño programa de consola en C# el cual consume un webservice y me regresa una respuesta que imprimo con `Console.Write(respuesta);` y esto es lo que imprime:

```
<Cancelacion xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" RfcEmisor="XAXX000000XAX" Fecha="2022-02-02T14:28:25" xmlns="http://cancelacfd.sat.gob.mx">
  <Folios>
   <UUID>dbfd9f2f-1b75-4e07-e1532-082d0dbc7712 </UUID>
   <UUIDEstatus>205</UUIDEstatus>
   <UUIDdescripcion>205 - UUID No existente, intente en 10 minutos. </UUIDdescripcion>  <UUIDfecha>2022-02-02T14:28:25 </UUIDfecha>
  </Folios>
 <Signature>no:signature</Signature>
</Cancelacion>
```

Después en PHP ejecuto este programa de la siguiente forma

```
$ejecuta= @exec("Cancelado.exe", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Pero aquí ya no me imprime todo sino solo el texto que esta dentro de los nodos

```
Array ( [0] => dbfd9f2f-1b75-4e07-e1532-082d0dbc7712 205205 - UUID No existente, intente en 10 minutos. 2022-02-02T14:29:44 no:signature )
```

El detalles es que en PHP necesito los valores de los nodos para pasarlos a variables y me lo está regresando todo en una cadena sin el formato XML.

Saben si debo agregar algún encabezado en PHP para que reconozca correctamente el respuesta o en en C# lo debe regresar de otra forma?

Comment: un simple comentario, creo que es correcto lo que te muestra ya que solo lo estas mostrando la informacion mas no estas parseando lo que obtienes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de buscar sobre XML en PHP logre solucionarlo con `simplexml_load_string` para convertir el string de XML en un objeto y de ahí a un arreglo. El código es el siguiente:

```
$xml = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($output[0]))), true);
```

Agregue `utf8_encode()` porque algunas respuesta contenían tildes.

Con esto ya pude acceder a los elementos así:

```
$xml['Folios']['UUID'];
$xml['Folios']['UUIDEstatus'];
$xml['Folios']['UUIDdescripcion'];
```